# Draw a verticle line between two vertically placed divs - CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve something like this

[image]

Circle with letters starts at starting of first div and second div with a line separater in between. Here the length of line should be calculated based on space in middle of two divs.  I tried couple of ways but no luck. Please suggest me an approach to do this.

**Update:**

I tried @Vadim answer, but in my case separater length should be dynamic, not static, and div's are like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first-div">
    <div class="letter">Q</div>
    <div>another div</div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-div">
     <div class="letter">A</div>
     <div>another div</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to draw vertical line between letters. Height of line should be dynamic according to inner divs height.

Comment: Please share your HTML and CSS, what you have tried so far

Comment: You can make a div and put that it in between or you cab use charecter map charecters in windows

Comment: @Duannx Thanks for reply.  My app is developing on react, am able to put circles with has letters in middle using a predefined react library . I just want to know, how to draw a vertical line between two vertically placed divs?

Comment: @Nani How should empty space appear between these "letters"? As I understood we have `.first-div` and `.second-div` and we should add line between them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flexbox to achieve desired layout:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  
  /* align items in one column and take space defined by content */
  /* this is used for centering separator */
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.letter {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  /* styles for text centering */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.separator {
  width: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  
  /* center horizontally */
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="letter">Q</div>
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="letter">A</div>
</div>
```